# Addressing a parent level of @CurrentIteration in the query [azure-devops-server]

Tags: azure-devops

I've been searching it for a longer while and still have no answer.
I would like to automate creation of a set of queries for the dashboard relevant to the particular quarter. Currently, queries are copied-pasted every quarter with updated iteration path under eg xx\2022 Q4, and the structure is as follows

2022 Q3

- Sprint 1
- Sprint 2
- Sprint 3
- Sprint 4

2022 Q4

- Sprint 1
- Sprint 2
- Sprint 3
- Sprint 4

I wanted to use `@CurrentIteration`, yet the problem is that then the query pulls out the results only of the current sprint instead of the whole quarter.

Is there any way to address the parent of `@CurrentIteration` in the query (so 2022 Q4 in this case instead of only Sprint 1) that would be automatically updated every quarter?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I did some research and test, the @CurrentIteration and there is currently no option to set it to parent level (2022 Q4) to include the entire quarter.

Maybe you could try to [create a sliding window of your team's iterations query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=azure-devops#create-a-sliding-window-of-your-teams-iterations-query) to check if it meet you requirements.

If not, you could use "[Request a feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion)" on the left side of Developer Community to open a new suggestion ticket.

Comment: Thank you for your respond! I forgot to write that I had tried a sliding window, but I couldn't find any solution that would work.